# How do I change text size and field size of a TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create an input similar like this (⬇) with `SwiftUI`.

[image]

I've made progress but I can't figure out how to change the height of the text fields and make the input text size bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change text size by changing the placeholder text's font size, which automatically adjusts the `TextField`'s height.

In your case, this looks pretty similar to what you asked for:

```
HStack {
        Group {
            TextField($str, placeholder: Text("A"))
            TextField($str, placeholder: Text("B"))
            TextField($str, placeholder: Text("C"))
            TextField($str, placeholder: Text("D"))
        }
        .frame(width: 60, height: nil)
        .padding(.all, 5)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .font(Font.system(size: 60, design: .default))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
```