# SwiftUI: Is it possible to automatically move to the next textfield after 1 character is entered?

Tags: textfield, swiftui

I trying to make a SwiftUI app where after entering one letter in a `TextField` the cursor automatically moves to the next `TextField`. The UI is pretty much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533834/how-do-i-change-text-size-and-field-size-of-a-textfield/56534242).

In Swift/IB, it looks like this was done with delegates and adding a target like in this post:
[How to move to the next UITextField automatically in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312756/how-to-move-to-the-next-uitextfield-automatically-in-swift)

But can't find any documentation for using delegates/targets in SwiftUI.

I tried following this post:
[SwiftUI TextField max length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476007/swiftui-textfield-max-length)
But this has not worked for me. Setting the `.prefix(1)` does not seem to make a difference. The `TextField` still accepts any amount of characters and when moved to the next `TextField` does not reduce the characters entered to only the first character.

In SwiftUI's current state, is it possible to automatically move to the next `TextField` after 1 character is entered?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you already mentioned your first bet - use `UIKit`. Instead of looking *only* at `UITextFields`, create a `UIViewController` with all your textfields (and logic)  and use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Yeah, that's a lot of work. The only other thought I have is to use `Compose` and add logic into it to "point" to which textbook should be next. Not sure about focus, but again, probably as much work as using a view controller representable.

Comment: Given how things stand, if you need *"advanced features"* on textfields, you are probably better off wrapping UITextField inside a Representable. After all, that is what the "pure" SwiftUI TextField seem to be doing anyway. You can see that is the case by simply observing notification `UITextField.textDidChangeNotification`. You'll see that it also fires for `TextField` and as its object, it will provide you with its related `UITextField`.

Comment: Thank you both for the responses. Hopefully SwiftUI will solve this in the future!

Comment: This might be helpful. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swiftui/jump-focus-between-a-series-of-textfields-pin-code-style-entry-widget/765

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in iOS 15 with `FocusState`

```
import SwiftUI
///Sample usage
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct PinParentView: View {
    @State var pin: Int = 12356
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(pin.description)
            PinView(pin: $pin)
        }
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct PinView: View {
    @Binding var pin: Int
    @State var pinDict: [UniqueCharacter] = []
    @FocusState private var focusedField: UniqueCharacter?
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            ForEach($pinDict, id: \.id, content: { $char in
                TextField("pin digit", text:
                            Binding(get: {
                    char.char.description
                }, set: { newValue in
                    let newest: Character = newValue.last  ?? "0"
                    //This check is only needed if you only want numbers
                    if Int(newest.description) != nil{
                        char.char = newest
                    }
                    //Set the new focus
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        setFocus()
                    }
                })
                ).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: char)
            })
            
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            //Set the initial value of the text fields
            //By using unique characters you can keep the order
            pinDict = pin.description.uniqueCharacters()
            
        })
    }
    func setFocus(){
        //Default to the first box when focus is not set or the user reaches the last box
        if focusedField == nil || focusedField == pinDict.last{
            focusedField = pinDict.first
        }else{
            //find the index of the current character
            let idx = pinDict.firstIndex(of: focusedField!)
            //Another safety check for the index
            if idx == nil || pinDict.last == pinDict[idx!]{
                focusedField = pinDict.first
            }else{
                focusedField = pinDict[idx! + 1]
            }
        }
        //Update the Binding that came from the parent
        setPinBinding()
    }
    ///Updates the binding from the parent
    func setPinBinding(){
        var newPinInt = 0
        for n in pinDict{
            if n == pinDict.first{
                newPinInt = Int(n.char.description) ?? 0
            }else{
                newPinInt = Int(String(newPinInt) + n.char.description) ?? 0
            }
        }
        pin = newPinInt
    }
}


//Convert String to Unique characers
extension String{
    func uniqueCharacters() -> [UniqueCharacter]{
        let array: [Character] = Array(self)
        return array.uniqueCharacters()
    }
    func numberOnly() -> String {
        self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-0123456789.").inverted)
    }
    
}
extension Array where Element == Character {
    
    func uniqueCharacters() -> [UniqueCharacter]{
        var array: [UniqueCharacter] = []
        
        for char in self{
            array.append(UniqueCharacter(char: char))
        }
        return array
    }
    
}

//String/Characters can be repeating so yu have to make them a unique value
struct UniqueCharacter: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable{
    var char: Character
    var id: UUID = UUID()
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct PinView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PinParentView()
    }
}
```